# Calling function passed into Angular directive returns the function rather than calling it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass a function into a directive using `&` in the directive's scope parameter:

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      'fn': '&',
    },
    link: function(scope,el, attrs){
      console.log(scope.fn());
    }
  }
});
```

I then call the function in `link` and log the return value.

In the template I pass a function that should just alert "ok" into the directive:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div my-directive fn="myFn"></div>
</div>
```

The code is in this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pGshl8jBxYxvqyBxwJDy?p=preview), but it logs the function rather than calling it:

```
function (){
    alert('ok')
}
```

Why is it not calling the function?

Answer (score 2):

`&` doesn't pass a function into the directive, it passes an expression. In that expression you need to call the function:

```
<div my-directive fn="myFn()"></div>
```

When doing just `myFn` Angular will evaluate the expression and just return the value of the function.